# Intel x86 HAXM installation error

Tags: android, android-studio

Hae . I'm trying to install intel HAXM and is giving me this error..Intel Virtualization is not turned on.However,i have already turned it on .. what might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have hypervison off
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
There's also the NX, XD bit setting. You can type 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Make sure you use the Haxm from the web site instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio). https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your question, exactly, but I strongly recommend using Genymotion for your emulation. I can't believe I waited so long to get it running. Genymotion runs smoother on my cheap laptop with an AMD processor than the Android Studio emulator does on my Intel powered gaming rig with HAXM. It has dramatically improved my iteration loop.